# inotifywait not triggering when files created from my node js app

Tags: node.js, inotify

This is my shel script.

```
while true
do
        inotifywait --exclude .swp -e create -e modify -e delete -e move  /etc/autogenerated

        echo "Folder state changed"

done
```

I am creating file inside /etc/autogenerated folder directly using NodeJS app. It is not trigging the inotifywait trigger.

But If I manually copy file from terminal it working file.

Any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [watchfile](https://gist.github.com/swarminglogic/8963507) from swarminglogic